# Multiple login/passwords to same real linux user for VSFTPD

Tags: ftp

I have a server (Ubuntu 12.10) running multiple websites, each with a different account.

I've configured VSFTPD to chroot these users in their respective folders, and all is working fine. As an example, I got user "foobar" that owns /srv/example.com.

Now I want a second **virtual** user that can only access a subdirectory, like /srv/example.com/images but with same user, group and pemissions of "foobar".

Is that possible? Or is there a better way?

(Note that apache is running apache2-mpm-itk, so when I access www.example.com, apache is dropping privileges to user foobar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create that second user with a home directory of  /srv/example.com/images but with the same UID/GID numbers as user foobar.

```
# id foobar
uid=500(foobar) gid=500(foobar) groups=500(foobar)
# adduser -o -u 500 -g 500 -d /srv/example.com/images foobar2
adduser: warning: the home directory already exists.
Not copying any file from skel directory into it.
# id foobar2
uid=500(foobar) gid=500(foobar) groups=500(foobar)
```

Comment: This seems to be a simple way to solve my problem. Any downsides of doing this? (I mean, is this a good practice?) Thank you

Comment: Many basic operations run around the UID/GID numbers and translate those numbers to human readable names. You can get interesting results when those mappings are one-to-many. Things shouldn't break, but for instance an `ls -l` may show foobar as the owner one time, and foobar2 a second time. An alternative could be to use your webserver configuration to create a single URL namespace from multiple file system locations, i.e. with an Apache `Alias /images/ /home/foobar2/images/` and then owners don't need to match.